# Concatenate data frames in R

Tags: r, concatenation, append

I have four data frames with different headers and different no of rows. I want to append all four data frames in one data frame leaving few rows empty between data frames in R. For example:

DF1:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

DF2:

[image]

DF3:

[image]

DF4:

[image]

Result DataFrame:

[image]

I tried rbind and bind_rows functions, but it did not give what I am looking for.

I want the following result after appending/concatenating the four data frames.

Answer (score 0):

`bind_rows()` is actually what you're wanting and then you would have to deal with the `NA`s from the missing columns that are not in all 4 dataframes

```
df5 <- bind_rows(df1,df2,df3,df4)
df5[is.na(df5)] <- ''
```

If you're wanting whats in your image then you would just make a list of dataframes

```
listOfFrames <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the result appears like below. I want all data frames one below another with their own headers.

Comment: Having them in a list is what you're looking for then.